# Understanding React Native Perf Monitor

Tags: react-native

What is JSC in the Perf Monitor and what does it represent? Also, what are the two levels of Views in Perf Monitor?

Comment: This talk from React Conf about perf tools might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MlT74erp60

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSC column represents the size of the JavaScriptCore managed heap -- how your app is allocating JS objects.

The two levels of the Views column is for Views that are on-screen, versus views that are off-screen or merged. You want to try to get those numbers to be as close as possible to avoid unnecessary layout calculation and processing.

Comment: - What exactly is a `View` here? A react component which is eventually rendered to the DOM or any component?
- What does it mean if Views "merge"?