# How to understand react native Performance Monitor view counts

Tags: react-native, react-native-screens

From what I understand the views tab on the react native performance monitor shows visible views/total or merged views.
From what I can gather... it's better to have these numbers as low as possible and as close together as possible: [react-native performance monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000291/react-native-performance-monitor) and [Understanding React Native Perf Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638313/understanding-react-native-perf-monitor?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I've got two results from the performance monitor:

Before enabling optimization:

[image]

After enabling optimization ([react-native-screens](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens) if you're curious):

[image]

As you can see the number of visible views is cut in half with the optimization turned on.

That brings me to my question:

1. What is the difference between rendering a visible view and a non-visible view? How are they treated differently by the phone?
2. Would reducing the visible views while leaving the total views makes a significant performance increase on its own? Why?

Comment: After reading the two linked SO threads and some other articles it's still not clear to me what "views" are meant to be here. Are "Views" in general all React components somehow involved in the rendered screen or only really mounted components?