# In React Native Perf Monitor, What is meaning views column?

Tags: react-native

I already read the question.

[Understanding React Native Perf Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638313/understanding-react-native-perf-monitor)

but I could not understand clearly.

[on react native docs perf monitor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txnQR.png)

The views column has two values.
I have two question.

1) What's meaning Views in this image?
2) Why divided 2 space in views column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

React-Native uses Views for layout of the application - this is basically done with the tags `View` and `Text`, and some other containers for lists etc.

The top Views number shows the number of views that are currently displayed on the screen.

The bottom Views number shows the total number of views that are currently being rendered (layout and drawing calculations are performed for them), including those that are off-screen or that could be merged (like nested Text nodes, for example).

Since calculating layout for views is work that takes time, minimizing the difference between those two numbers is a way to optimize your app.